# Does fouriernc contain sans serif fonts?

Tags: fonts, microtype

Does `fouriernc` contain sans serif font? If not, which type is actually used for it? Is this type scalable?

My problem shows not so minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{empheq,mathtools,xspace} %   
\newcommand{\T}{\text{\sffamily\slshape T\,}\xspace}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
I would like \T to be slanted and sans serif letter. I use it in text as well as in equations:
\[\T = a + b \quad\mathrm{and}\quad \int_\T = \cdots    \]
How to achieve this with considering used fonts?

\bigskip\sffamily
Transformacijo pravokotnega pulza preprosto izračunamo z definiciji Fourierove transformacije, v kateri upoštevamo lastnosti simetrij:
\begin{align}
X(\omega)   &   = \int^{\infty}_{\infty} p_\T \exp(-j\omega t)\; dt \\
            &   = \int^{-\T/2}_{\T/2} \sin(\omega t)\, dt
                = 2\frac{\sin(\omega\T/2)}{\omega}
                = \T\frac{\sin(\omega\T/2)}{\omega\T/2}
                            \notag                                  \\
            &   = \T\mathrm{Sa}(\omega\T/2)\ ,
\end{align}
kjer je $p_\T$ pravokotni pulz.
\end{document}
```

which gives error:

pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.

If I remove `microtype` package, all works fine. From this I have concluded, that sans serif font are not part of `fouriernc` and that for it is used some substitution which is can not be used with `microtype`. Do I have right?

Which fonts for sans serif is the most accordant with `fouriernc`? I prefer one which has the same height for lowercase and uppercase letters as that of roman font.

Comment: Please make your code minimal. What does all the TikZ and colour box stuff have to do with anything? By the way, why don't you just look at the properties in your viewer when you produce a PDF without `microtype`?

Comment: Your code works fine here when I complete it so it stands a chance. All fonts used are type1. Is it possible that you do not have `cm-super` installed? Not that CM is likely a good match if you are using `fouriernc`, but it should work. By the way, why `\ensuremath{\text{...`? The `\ensuremath` seems to serve no purpose.

Comment: Compiles fine here. In any case about those three macros you have, it's probably better to use a known good defintion for differentials (I would also drop `\ensuremath` and `\xspace` from that macro) `\newcommand*{\T}{\textsf{\slshape T\/}}`, `\newcommand*{\ud}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}i}`, `\newcommand*{\udt}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t}`. Even may be do `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfsl}{T1}{cmss}{m}{it}` and then `\newcommand*{\T}{\mathsfsl{T}}`.

Comment: @cfr, I was not shure what is cause of my problems, so I strip my real file to this tcolor box, where I observe the problem. Now, after received answer and comments, I'm now able significantly reduce it. And I haven't installed cm-super fonts.

Comment: @Zarko That's why you need to test to create a minimal example. You comment stuff out and recompile. If the problem remains, the commented code can be deleted. Eventually, you have the minimum needed to reproduce the issue. It is just a mechanical process - you can guess what is most likely the problem and try that first, if you wish. If you're right, it saves some time; if not you just try the things you don't suspect until you find it. Very rarely, this process fails. But that is very, very rare. It has happened to me once so far in years of using LaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fouriernc` does not specify a sans serif font. By default, you will therefore get Computer Modern Sans. Since you are loading `fontenc` with option `T1`, these will be postscript type1 versions from, usually, `cm-super`. And, indeed, completing your document and compiling to PDF throws no error and shows that all fonts are, indeed, scalable type1:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
TAXDKT+CenturySchL-Roma              Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       7  0
MRDFER+SFSI1000                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       8  0
TYVRVL+Fourier-Math-Symbols          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       9  0
DRJIAH+CenturySchL-Ital              Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      10  0
HDYCOO+Fourier-Math-Extension        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      11  0
ZUELID+SFSI0800                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      12  0
KPCTUF+CenturySchL-Bold              Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      13  0
LTVCOH+SFSX0900                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      14  0
AOTEQD+SFSS0900                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      15  0
WSBTSK+Fourier-Math-Letters-Italic   Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      16  0
YXUCWV+SFSI0900                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      17  0
```

This is not to say that CM is a great match in this case, but scalability ought not to be a problem. Check that `cm-super` is installed. Or load `lmodern` before loading `fouriernc`.